# How to add a zero to the output of the String.length method if the length is less than 10?

Tags: java, string, string-length

I have a string as a parameter in my method and i am trying to print the length of the string in which i have succeded but I want to add a zero in front of the length if it is less than 10.

I am getting the int cannot be referenced error, and not sure what the correct way of doing this is.

```
public void sendMessage(String message) throws ProtocolException {
    physicalLayer.sendFrame("<" + "E" + "-"
        + message.length().toString().padleft(2, '0')
        + "-" + message + "-" + "00" + ">");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Primitive types don't have methods. So you can't call toString() on an int. Google should help you find out how to transform an int to a String. Note that String doesn't have any padLeft() method. It seems you're calling imaginary methods, instead of reading the javadoc. Don't do that. It won't lead you anywhere.

Comment: `message.length()` returns a primitive `int` that doesn't have any methods (i.e. there's no `.toString()`.  Either use a `Formatter` or do `Integer.valueOf(message.length())`

Comment: I get it now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

String.format("%02d", message.length())